# Is there something wrong with Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Bayes' theorem (simplified): $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A) \times P(B|A)}{P(B)}$

Per the books/teachers I've had the honor to meet, the probability of an event $P(E)$ is such that $0 \leq P(E) \leq 1$ i.e. $P(E) = 0$ is **possible**.

But if $P(B) = 0$ then, $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A) \times P(B|A)}{P(B)} = P(A|B) = \frac{P(A) \times P(B|A)}{0} =$ undefined.

How do I resolve this problem, if it *is* a problem in the first place?

Comment: The full statement of this theorem specifically excludes the case of $P(B) = 0$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem

Comment: Gracias @lisyarus, but in *philosophy* we routinely ask questions on *impossibility* e.g. if souls are *impossible* then (it's *likely that*) there's no afterlife.

Comment: @AgentSmith Huh?

Comment: @AspiringMat, yes, huh!

Comment: Your question reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox

Comment: @AgentSmith This is mathematics stackexchange, not philosophy stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

$P(B) = 0$ means that $B$ itself is impossible, or at least impossible to have happen "randomly".  Which means among other things that $P(B|A)$ is also $0$, so really you have $0/0$, which is indeterminate and could take on any limiting value, which makes sense, you're asking about impossible situations here.

Comment: Much obliged. can we express probabilities as *functions* and then rework the problem in terms of *limits*?

Answer (score 1):

$P(A|B)$ yields the probability of $A$ given $B$ occurs. If $P(B) = 0$, then $P(A|B)$ being undefined makes sense because how can you find the probability of $A$ given $B$ occurs if $B$ never occurs? It's impossible and therefore undefined; so it's not necessarily a problem, but there's no point in doing $P(A|B)$ if you know that $P(B) \text{ is } 0$, though it is logically consistent.

Comment: So we won't be able to solve problems like: if X is **impossible** then the *likelihood* of Y given P(X) = 0, is ? ?

Comment: We can answer that question, but that is different definition-wise from P(A|B). P(A|B) assumes that B does occur as that is a given. In your example, the given is the probability of X.

Comment: The probability that God exists given that miracles are impossible?

Comment: I see the light, $P(B) = 1 - P(\neg B)$. So if $P(M)$ = the probability that miracles occur = $0$, then $P(\neg M) = 1$ = the probability that miracles don't occur. So $P(G|M) = $ the probability that God exists *given* that miracles are *impossible* should be rephrased as $P(G|\neg M)$